# R: Efficient formula creation within `lm`

Tags: r, automation, paste, lm

I am looking to write generic code for some iterative modeling I am doing on genetic data.

Here is a subset of my dataframe:

```
> head(exprTarget)
      patient CDR Diagnosis diag_key  UNC93B1     CTSC     PLEK   LGALS9      GRN    CYTH4     C1QA     C1QC     C1QB   LAPTM5     CTSS    FCER1G   ALOX5AP
16955   16955   2       MCI        1 2.468387 3.306170 1.669025 2.197085 4.817537 2.303606 3.126281 3.537686 4.077572 4.660030 2.960342 1.0880424 2.0820685
16365   16365   5        AD        2 2.312767 3.205852 1.276787 1.942052 4.924718 2.461212 2.641784 3.592875 3.758567 4.215387 2.536174 0.9872809 0.7559553
17155   17155   5        AD        2 3.276758 4.039103 2.482880 3.347225 5.465345 2.990894 6.004585 6.108294 6.762214 5.708623 4.358901 2.5924355 3.6172763
17135   17135   5        AD        2 2.245509 3.056953 1.877469 2.083920 4.492934 1.827284 2.584534 3.012729 3.369049 3.892801 2.990098 0.7350252 1.1568519
16625   16625   4        AD        2 2.575806 3.978674 2.060418 2.327522 4.981906 2.685569 4.694788 4.725954 5.460863 5.260811 4.021172 2.5871655 3.3241311
16295   16295   4        AD        2 3.107424 3.701104 2.880653 2.880653 5.115831 2.723281 4.224342 4.717155 5.110232 5.031450 3.980189 2.0809520 1.9699207
```

I am trying to use `diag_key` as my response variable with all columns to its right acting as the predictor variables, i.e. the desired formula is:

```
lm(diag_key ~ . - patient - CDR - Diagnosis, data= exprTarget)
```

I want to make this more generic. Specifically, I want to be able to pass only the column number that separates my clinical annotations from the gene expression data, in the above example this would be column 4 `diag_key`, although for different implementations it could vary.

My current objective is to recreate the above formula with only this information. Here is my current attempt, note that `response` corresponds to the separating column number, i.e. 4 in the above example:

```
 clinical<- colnames(exprTarget)[1:(response-1)]

 lm(as.formula(paste("exprTarget[,response] ~ . ",clinical, sep = "-")), data= exprTarget)
```

This command generates the formula `exprTarget[, 4] ~ . - patient`, so clearly the issue is that in using `paste` to connect the start of the formula with the columns I want to remove, only the first item in the list is pasted.

Any help navigating this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructing the formula can be avoided like this:

```
nc <- ncol(exprTarget)
fm <- lm(exprTarget[response:nc])
```

but if you really want the formula anyways:

```
formula(fm)
## diag_key ~ UNC93B1 + CTSC + PLEK + LGALS9 + GRN + CYTH4 + C1QA + 
##  C1QC + C1QB + LAPTM5 + CTSS + FCER1G + ALOX5AP
```

**Note:** The input used in the above in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
      patient CDR Diagnosis diag_key  UNC93B1     CTSC     PLEK   LGALS9      GRN    CYTH4     C1QA     C1QC     C1QB   LAPTM5     CTSS    FCER1G   ALOX5AP
16955   16955   2       MCI        1 2.468387 3.306170 1.669025 2.197085 4.817537 2.303606 3.126281 3.537686 4.077572 4.660030 2.960342 1.0880424 2.0820685
16365   16365   5        AD        2 2.312767 3.205852 1.276787 1.942052 4.924718 2.461212 2.641784 3.592875 3.758567 4.215387 2.536174 0.9872809 0.7559553
17155   17155   5        AD        2 3.276758 4.039103 2.482880 3.347225 5.465345 2.990894 6.004585 6.108294 6.762214 5.708623 4.358901 2.5924355 3.6172763
17135   17135   5        AD        2 2.245509 3.056953 1.877469 2.083920 4.492934 1.827284 2.584534 3.012729 3.369049 3.892801 2.990098 0.7350252 1.1568519
16625   16625   4        AD        2 2.575806 3.978674 2.060418 2.327522 4.981906 2.685569 4.694788 4.725954 5.460863 5.260811 4.021172 2.5871655 3.3241311
16295   16295   4        AD        2 3.107424 3.701104 2.880653 2.880653 5.115831 2.723281 4.224342 4.717155 5.110232 5.031450 3.980189 2.0809520 1.9699207"
exprTarget <- read.table(text = Lines)
response <- 4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reformulate` for this. I've based it on the column name of the response, as that seems safer than using the column index directly, but you can of course just use the column index instead.

```
resp_col = "diag_key"
idx = match(resp_col, names(exprTarget))

my_formula = reformulate(names(exprTarget)[(idx+1):ncol(exprTarget)], response=names(exprTarget)[idx])
```

> ```
> diag_key ~ UNC93B1 + CTSC + PLEK + LGALS9 + GRN + CYTH4 + C1QA + 
>     C1QC + C1QB + LAPTM5 + CTSS + FCER1G + ALOX5AP
> ```

You can package this into a function:

```
lm_form = function(data, resp_col) {

  idx = match(resp_col, names(data))

  form = reformulate(names(data)[(idx+1):ncol(data)], response=names(data)[idx])

  lm(form, data=data)
}

my_model = lm_form(exprTarget, "diag_key")
```